# Extending Zend\View\Helper\Url in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, urlhelper, viewhelper

I wrote a simple url view helper, that extends `Zend\View\Helper\Url` and attached it to the `ViewHelperManager`:

**`MyNamespace\View\Helper\Url`**

```
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\Url as ZendUrl;

class Url extends ZendUrl {
    
    public function __invoke($name = null, array $params = array(), $options = array(), $reuseMatchedParams = false) {
        $link = parent::__invoke($name, $params, $options, $reuseMatchedParams);
        ...
        return $link;
    }
    
}
```

**`Application\Module`**

```
namespace Application;

use ...

class Module {
    
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
        $application = $mvcEvent->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $viewHelperManager->setInvokableClass('url', 'MyNamespace\View\Helper\Url');
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Now the application throws an exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteStackInterface instance provided' in /var/www/foo/bar/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php on line 76
>
> Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: No RouteStackInterface instance provided in /var/www/foo/bar/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php on line 76

I debugged both `Url` classes. Wenn `MyNamespace\View\Helper\Url` is used, the method `Zend\View\Helper\Url#setRouter(...)` is not called and the router is not set. Don't get why...

How to get it working?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php#L63-L78

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think, it helps to understand the problem. The class of the URL view helper is hard coded ([line 64](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ViewHelperManagerFactory.php#L64)). That means for me, that the URL view helper cannot be extended without to rewrite `Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory#createService(...)`. Right?

Comment: Well you could just create your own factory and inject the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested this so I don't know if it works, I am just guessing:

Replace:

```php
$viewHelperManager->setInvokableClass('url', 'MyNamespace\View\Helper\Url');
```

with:

```php
$viewHelperManager->setFactory('url', function ($sm) use($serviceLocator) {
    $helper = new \MyNamespace\View\Helper\Url;
    $router = Console::isConsole() ? 'HttpRouter' : 'Router';
    $helper->setRouter($serviceLocator->get($router));

    $match = $serviceLocator->get('application')
    ->getMvcEvent()
    ->getRouteMatch();

    if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
        $helper->setRouteMatch($match);
    }

    return $helper;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use initializers!

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyUrl' => 'MyModule\View\Helper\MyUrl'
    ),
    'initializers' => array(
        function ($instance, $sm) {
            if ($instance instanceof \Zend\View\Helper\Url) {
                $serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();

                $router = \Zend\Console\Console::isConsole() ? 'HttpRouter' : 'Router';
                $instance->setRouter($serviceLocator->get($router));

                $match = $serviceLocator->get('application')
                    ->getMvcEvent()
                    ->getRouteMatch();

                if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
                    $instance->setRouteMatch($match);
                }
            }
        }
    )
)
```

And You can extend \Zend\View\Helper\Url as You want it

```
namespace MyModule\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\Url as ZendUrl;

class MyUrl extends ZendUrl {

    public function __invoke() {
        return parent::__invoke('MyRoute');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this questions is quite old, figured it might be worth adding a configuration based override here as well using a factory registered with the `HelperPluginManager`:

Inside the `module.config.php`:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'factories'=> array(
        'url' => 'Application\View\Helper\UrlFactory',
    )
),
```

And the view helper plugin factory itself:

```
<?php

namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Console\Console;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\View\Helper\Url as BaseUrlHelper;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager;

class UrlFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $helperPluginManager
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $helperPluginManager)
    {
        /**
         * @var $helperPluginManager HelperPluginManager
         * @var $router RouteStackInterface
         */
        $serviceLocator = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
        $helper = new Url();

        $router = Console::isConsole() ? 'HttpRouter' : 'Router';
        $router = $serviceLocator->get($router);
        $helper->setRouter($router);

        $match = $serviceLocator->get('application')
            ->getMvcEvent()
            ->getRouteMatch()
        ;

        if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
            $helper->setRouteMatch($match);
        }

        return $helper;
    }
}
```

The trick here really is that in this factory, one only receives the `HelperPluginManager` service locator. To access other services, one needs to fetch the global service locator first (which is done by the `use`ing the global service locator from outside the closure in all other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Aydin's solution worked for me, I put the code, more or less untouched in the getViewHelperConfig of the module.php

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            .....
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'modalurl'            => function ($helperPluginManager) {
                $serviceLocator = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $view_helper =  new \Application\View\Helper\ModalUrl();
                $router = \Zend\Console\Console::isConsole() ? 'HttpRouter' : 'Router';
                $view_helper->setRouter($serviceLocator->get($router));

                $match = $serviceLocator->get('application')
                    ->getMvcEvent()
                    ->getRouteMatch();

                if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
                    $view_helper->setRouteMatch($match);
                }

                return $view_helper;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```